# Is it okay to allocate more memory than you need for array when you do not know exact amount of elements but can estimate upper bound?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

C++.

I want to create an array and store elements in it. And I can estimate upper bound for amount of elements that would be true for most cases, let's say about 98% of cases. Is it better in terms of speed and beauty to create static array with size equal to upper bound instead of dynamic allocation? 
To be more specific, let's say that amount of elements varying between 10000 and 60000 and 2 bytes per element. And in very rare cases that amount can be higher than 60000(in such case I'll have to make reallocation).

Is it okay to statically allocate array of size 60000 and use part of it, and in some cases reallocate to bigger size, or this practice is too ugly?

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: Speed and beauty are different goals. Dynamic allocation is more graceful, but static allocation (with occasional reallocation) *might* be faster (you must test to be sure).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::vector`, which lets you resize as needed and reserve an estimated maximum size to improve performance. You can even make this static/global if you want to, but then you have the usual issues with global variables.

Unless you are creating new instances of the vector very frequently, which I doubt with such a large size, this should have good performance.

Comment: Thank you for advise, I'm not very expirieced in STL, looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The template `std::vector` is made to exactly tackle such problems. It will automatically allocate new memory for new elements, ensuring efficient use of memory, and preventing time expensive operations, like reallocation, as well.